# How to make a link on my footer trigger a pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to trigger a pop up form after clicking the ****4th** link** on my footer.

This current method works with another button on my site but not with the link in my footer.

Why is this?

**HTML:**

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wordpress/home' ) ); ?>" class="footer-link-text">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wordpress/portfolio/' ) ); ?>"class="footer-link-text">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wordpress/about-me/' ) ); ?>"class="footer-link-text">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"class="contact-link-footer">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('contact-link-footer').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
  $('body').css('overflow','hidden')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the next: Change document.getElementById(...) by document. getElementsByClassName(...)[0] , the zero is to get the first element of array of elements that have same class in the DOM

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('contact-link-footer')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Click in Contact');
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
});
```

Comment: Does the job but i would assign classes wich are already in the stylesheet to avoid inline styling in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You are using an id-selector but you have a class :)
'contact-link-footer' is at the moment the class of your link and not the id